# Rails JSON using RABL, showing parent attribute?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rabl

I have the following RABL file in my Rails 3.2 application:

```
collection @results.limit(5)

attributes :date, :client_id

child :client do
  attributes :Surname
end

child :animal do
  attributes :AnimalName
end
```

I would like to add the name of the user that the result belongs to. Everything I have read in the RABL documentation seem to suggest that only `child` and `node` are available.

How could I get a parents attribute within the above code? Just doing the following returns NULL, obviously!

```
child :animal do
  attributes :AnimalName
end
```

Is this possible?

Current JSON output:

```
{
date: "2013-06-25T19:36:11+01:00",
client_id: 88172,
client: {
Surname: "Strange"
},
animal: {
AnimalName: "Ria"
}
},
```

Desired output:

```
{
date: "2013-06-25T19:36:11+01:00",
client_id: 882372,
client: {
Surname: "Summer"
},
animal: {
AnimalName: "Ria"
},
user: {
UserName: "Danny"
}
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom node that adds in the user data:

```
collection @results.limit(5)

attributes :date, :client_id

node :user do |report|
  partial('users/show', :object => report.user)
end
```

This is assuming that you want the whole user/show template.

If you just want the name key/value:

```
node :user do |report|
 { :name => report.user.name }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've added the expected JSON to my question.

Comment: I'm trying the `Add user as child` method currently, I've added the show.json.rabl file within users and added your example code. It just returns `null`. I can't figure it out!

Comment: It looks like the `extends` option is just for templates of attribute sets but doesn't contain any data. The results.json just returns `user: null`.

Comment: do you have a rabl template set up for users/show.rabl? if not, you could create one or just put in attributes for the user directly in this template. that `extends yadda` is just like rendering a partial in a normal rails view, but you need the other template available.

Comment: to clarify, do your Results and User models have ActiveRecord relations between them? `belongs_to :user`

Comment: Yes I've added a user/show.rabl and added the attribute options. I also have the relations up and running.